# Changing address/value of dll file with IDA Pro

Tags: assembly, dll, reverse-engineering, decompiling, ida

I am writing with a very primitive question in my opinion, since I could not find really similar problems.

I am using IDA Pro.
I have a dll file (associated with the server part of the game, I don’t know the specific purpose) and I need to replace all current uses of the IP address with my own. From what I see, the address comes first, which I can change:
[Address change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbqQV.png)

But as for the second part (where probably the value is stored), I can't figure out how to change it:
[second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otwot.png)

Thanks

Comment: Just use a hex editor to change the bytes `192.168.200.133` - which is a C string and thus NULL-terminated - to whatever values you wish.  As you probably know, you need to ensure that the size of the DLL does not change after saving the change, so pad the string with extra NULL(s) if the length of new IP address string is smaller than the original string.

Answer (score -1):

`a192168200133` is a very weird way how to store IP address `192.168.200.133`.
Such IPv4 address could be saved in memory in binary form as `0xC0A8C885`, however [sockaddr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2) requires the address in *network byte order* (big endian), i.e. `0x85C8A8C0`.

If the address is hardwired in the DLL, I would search it for 32bit integers `0xC0A8C885` or `0x85C8A8C0` and replace them with values corresponding with your desired address.

Comment: `a192168200133` is a user-assigned name in IDA PRO for the NULL terminated string `192.168.200.133`.  Nothing more.